# What is the correct way to access a specific help file in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, if you type `:help` into the status bar, you get a window with this (contents truncated to the relevant bits):

```
*help.txt*      For Vim version 7.4.  Last change: 2012 Dec 06

                    VIM - main help file

...

USER MANUAL: These files explain how to accomplish an editing task.

Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and hit CTRL-].


|usr_toc.txt|   Table Of Contents

Getting Started ~
|usr_01.txt|  About the manuals
|usr_02.txt|  The first steps in Vim
|usr_03.txt|  Moving around
|usr_04.txt|  Making small changes
|usr_05.txt|  Set your settings
|usr_06.txt|  Using syntax highlighting
|usr_07.txt|  Editing more than one file
|usr_08.txt|  Splitting windows
|usr_09.txt|  Using the GUI
```

Say I want to see more information about this item `|usr_07.txt|`, what command do I type?

I tried this:

> Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and hit CTRL-].

But my terminal window has mapped `ctrl -` to "decrease text".

Comment: If you're using `vim` in a terminal window, you can also jump to a topic, with a mouse double click (left button)

Comment: When you say topic, do you mean like place the mouse on `|usr_07.txt|` and double click? didnt work for me

Comment: Are you using gnome or kde? I should have specified `gnome-terminal`

Comment: In general the command is C] 
the hypen is shown to demonstrate a key combination. It's not `Control -`
it's `Control ]'

Comment: @bdowning using gnome, when I looked at the token `ctrl - ]` I mistook the `]` as being a closing parenthesis for a longer statement, and intuitively I would  equate `ctrl + ]` to a *press ctrl and also press ]*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
:help usr_01.txt
```

to access a specific file. Usually more usefully you can jump to a particular topic:

```
:help syntax
:help wq
:help CTRL-]
```

[This last](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#CTRL-]) notes that you can also use <kbd>Ctrl-Click</kbd> with the mouse, and double-click works too.

You [can also use `g]`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#%3Atselect) to access [tagselect](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#%3Atselect), which offers a list that you can select from with just numbers and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In many cases that will be a list of one item, but it still avoids using <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> at any point.

Some other commands you could use to follow these links are also [listed in `:help tagsrch.txt`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html).

Comment: `:help usr_01.txt` did it, doh, I was trying with `|` character

Answer (score 3):

`CTRL-]` means hold down `control` and hit the `]` key (not `-`).

Answer (score 2):

Paul’s answer above explains how to jump from link to link in the vim help, but you can also open the file directly, if you know what you want to open, with eg, `:help usr_01.txt`